# correct syntax, for webkit in the firefox

Tags: webkit

Trying to get animation working in firefox, have working in chrome perfectly fine.  Can anyone point me in the correct direction??

```
#LeftDoor{
left:0px;

@-moz-animation: leftDoorOpen 4s ease 4s; 
@-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}



@-moz-keyframes leftDoorOpen {
   from {
   -moz-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0deg);
   -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;


}
to {
   -moz-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(90deg);
   -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;


    }
 }
```

I have created a fiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/Dgy2Q/  cant get this to work in firefox, chrome works great

Comment: you should link a jsfiddle as well so we don't have to create our own html markup to help with your code